# in the sentence "The farmer has herds of cattle on his farm" will cattle be a collective noun?

Tags: grammaticality

in the sentence "The farmer has herds of cattle on his farm " , will 'cattle' be a common noun ?

Comment: *Cattle* is a plural common noun. *Herd* is the collective noun for a group of cattle (and you can have several herds). A dictionary should say that.

Comment: It's a common noun rather than a proper noun. It's very uncommon (different sense) in that it doesn't have a singular-referencing form when it would seem to require one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Herd is a collective noun, as it refers to a group of cattle and you can have multiple groups, hence multiple herds.The basic constituent of a herd remains the same whether it is one herd or several, it still refers to a group/s of animals.
2. Cattle is a common noun.Where is the debate?

Comment: A plural common noun, without a singular.